# chaining requests with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I need to make about 5 chaining requests for example I have 5 different calls and I want to make them serial not parallel in specific order.

Here are some examples of my observables

```
Observable<ResponseBody> textsCall=EndpointFactory.provideEndpoint().getTexts(textsTask.getLanguage())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<AirportCombo> routesCall=EndpointFactory.provideEndpoint().getRoutes()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Actually, I don't know what function does it on rx java.

Earlier I've implemented parallel requests, now I need serial.

If you need parallel approach here you are:

```
Observable<ResponseResult> combined = Observable.zip(textsCall, routesCall, (textsBody, airportCombo) -> {
            //some parsing and other logic
            return new ResponseResult(flag);
        });
```

Comment: would typically use `flatMap()` to chain requests like this...particularly if result of first call is need when making 2nd call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use flatmap function for this exact purpose

```
textsCall
 .flatMap(new Func1 < ResponseBody, Observable < AirportCombo >> () {
  @Override
  public Observable < AirportCombo > call(ResponseBody valueA) {
   // code to save data from service valueA to db
   // call service B
   return routesCall;
  }
 })
 .flatMap(new Func1 < AirportCombo, Observable < ValueC >> () {
  @Override
  public Observable < ValueC > call(AirportCombo valueB) {
   // code to save data from service valueB to db
   // call service C
   return observableC;
  }
 })
 .flatMap(new Func1 < ValueC, Observable < ValueD >> () {
  @Override
  public Observable < ValueD > call(ValueC valueC) {
   // code to save data from service valueC to db
   // call service D
   return observableD;
  }
 })
 .flatMap(new Func1 < ValueD, Observable < ValueFinal >> () {
  @Override
  public Observable < ValueFinal > call(ValueD valueC) {
   // code to save data from service valueD to db
   // call Final Service
   return observableFinal;
  }
 })
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Subscriber < ValueFinal > () {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {}

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(ValueFinal fooB) {
   // code to save data from service ValueFinal to db

  }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, i appreciate

Comment: what about doOnNext approach is it ok?

 .doOnNext(modelA -> db.store(modelA))
        .flatMap(modelA -> apiService.B())
        .doOnNext(modelB -> db.store(modelB));

Comment: any ideas how to handle errors here?

Comment: @jenya doNext also no issues

Comment: is there a way to stop this chain after some flatmap failed?

Comment: @janya if any error occurs in any service come in onError

Comment: I got it. I think i will create some custom exceptions for my purposes and will throw them when needed

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza Ya correct